# Remove Specific Elements from 2D Array

Tags: php

```
Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
                      [0] => a
                      [1] => b  
                      [2] => c
                      [3] => c 
                      [4] => d
                     )
       )
```

I have 2D array as of `$arr[0][$i];`

`$i` is the only part that increments, whereas `0` is fixed.

**1. I need to remove element a and b via a search inside the array.**

*My attempt did not delete the elements:*

```
$posts = array_diff($posts, array("a", "b"));
```

**2. I would like to eliminate all duplicated values and leave only one i.e. removing all c's except one c.**

The final output would be:

```
Array ( 
        [0] => Array (  
                      [0] => c
                      [1] => d
                     )
       )
```

I'm trying to figure it out, however, your help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: I think you stopped at the half to solve your problem. Instead of `$post` all at once you need to diff *each* value of the `$post` array. As you wrote it's 2D, so deal with it as if it is 2D and not 1D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you select the inner array it should work as you aspect it

```
$posts[0] = array_diff($posts[0], array("a", "b"));
```

The elimination should work that way

```
$post[0] = array_values(array_unique($posts[0]));
```